# Update a table column based on existing columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql database:
I need to update a field in a table using another field in the same table. Example:
My table `TABLE1` contains two fields `FIELD1` and `FIELD2`. I need to do something along the line

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET FIELD1 = (SELECT CONCAT('xyz',`FIELD2`) FROM TABLE1)
```

I need to update the field for all the records. No conditions.
I tried executing the query but got an error

> You can't specify target table 'TABLE1' for update in FROM clause.

Can someone tell me how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET FIELD1 = concat('xyz', FIELD2)
where FIELD1 <> concat('xyz', FIELD2)
```

Comment: I updated the query. If it times out run it again. It will update the records that are not updated yet. You can also add a `limit 5000` to it to update in intervals.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BrianS: How does this answer not provide an answer? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: I think this was the answer I was on in the review queue when a connectivity problem made things go wonky. (Note that the above comment is a stock post from the review queue.) However, even if it is an answer to the question, it could use some elaboration. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET FIELD1 = CONCAT('xyz',`FIELD2`)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BrianS: How does this answer not provide an answer? It is the answer to the question, based on my understanding of the question.